# How to change MariaDB's data directory?

Tags: centos, mariadb

I use CentOS7 as my system

I tried to change the data direction on MariaDB 10.1.43

I follow the process on internet and all show to change the `datadir=/var/lib/mysql/` in `my.cnf`

but the problem is there is no `my.cnf` file in my computer

only a `my.cnf.d` folder with a server.cnf file in it

I type `datadir=/newpath/` in this `server.cnf`

but it didn't work, the `datadir` that mariaDB shows is still `/var/lib/mysql/`

what should I do for now? how can I find this `my.cnf` file?

Comment: Use ps to see what parameters are on `mysqld`.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%dir%';`

Comment: same,datadir is `/var/lib/mysql/`

Comment: ```mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"```  lists the configuration files.

Comment: It shows me three ways `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` `/etc/my.cnf` `~/.my.cnf` but still no `my.cnf` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question. But wanted to add an answer that worked for me on a legacy machine running MariaDB 10.1.43 and CentOS 6.

Within the `/etc/my.cnf` file add this under `[client-server]` to look like this:

```
[client-server]
port=3306
socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Then, within the `/etc/my.cnf.d` folder in the `server.cnf` file add this under `[mysqld]` to look like this:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/home/mysql
socket=/home/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I moved the data to the `/home` directory, which is a newly mounted volume with additional space for this machine.

The next part of my answer is out of scope for this question. But [the instructions here](https://www.tecmint.com/change-default-mysql-mariadb-data-directory-in-linux/) worked like a charm for moving your MySQL/MariaDB data directory. Semi-pro tip: Be sure to follow the RedHat/CentOS step to add the security context.